# Fire and Water, Hear Me Roar

Tags: riddle, word, knowledge, rhyme

> My first is the first of an outrageous utterance
>   My second the second of appropriate circumstance
>   My third's the essence of heat, why anything cools
>   My last a procedure, all about the rules
>   Take the B's from my one
>   And the A's from my two
>   And with three's A & B's
>   My name I'll tell you

What am I?

---

**HINT 1:**

> I do not like coffee.

**HINT 2:**

> Familiarity with how spider nests work can be an advantage in solving the puzzle.

**HINT 3:**

> The first four lines will each produce a word which together form a fairly familiar abbreviation. The next three lines form a 3-digit number.

Comment: For some reason I thought it was abracadabra :P

Comment: @MrPie I suppose the A's and B's would give that impression xd

Comment: Hint 2 rot13(jnf jura V jrag "Ab ab ab" naq yrsg guvf chmmyr. Fcvqref = abcr abcr abcr)

Comment: @Avi I just put a bounty on the question. Hopefully, it helps you overcome your fear of the cute crawlers :)

Comment: @greysaff rot13(Fgvyy 6 yrtf gbb znal sbe zr. Sbe gur svefg uvag V'z guvaxvat "onfgneq" nf vg unf n "on" ng gur ortvaavat. Sbe gur guveq uvag, V'z guvaxvat (hayvxryl) gurezbqlanzvpf be (cebonoyl) urng pncnpvgl. Va nal pnfr, +1 sbe guvf chmmyre.)

Comment: Is this related to thermodynamics directly? Just wondering if I'm heading in the right direction....

Comment: @car Only the clue in the third line has any remote connection to  thermodynamics.

Comment: @greysaff rot13(Qbrf gur cneg nobhg abg yvxvat pbssrr ersre gb "oneovghengr"? Gurl'er qrcerffnagf, juvyr pnssrvar vf n fgvzhynag?)

Comment: @greysaff rot13(Ner lbh fher lbh zrna gb ersre gb fcvqre arfgf naq abg jrof? "Ivoengvba" pbhyq jbex sbe pyhr 3, naq gung vf n xrl pbzcbarag bs ubj fcvqre JROF jbex. Nz V ba gur evtug genpx?)

Comment: rot13(Fbzrubj V'z trggvat gur vzcerffvba gung vg'f n 4-yrggre jbeq, vs gur sbyybjvat vf pbeerpg: uvag 3 vf ragebcl, juvpu unf flzoby "F", naq uvag 4 pbhyq or ersreevat gb n cebtenzzvat ynathntr, fhpu nf "P".)

Comment: @ribs2spare rot13(Gur pbssrr uvag vf sbe gur svany nafjre naq abg sbe gur vavgvny uvagf. Lbh ner evtug gung "fcvqre arfg" vf abg gur nccebcevngr grez ohg gung vf nyfb eryngrq gb gur svany fgrc (abg gur 3eq yvar))

Comment: @Avi rot13(Gur nafjref gb gur svefg 4 yvarf pna hygvzngryl or erqhprq gb n "4-yrggre jbeq" vaqrrq! Ohg gur yrggref lbh pheeragyl unir ner hasbeghangryl vapbeerpg.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are:

> **HTTP 418** - i.e. HTTP response code 418, "The server refuses the attempt to brew coffee with a teapot." (Which I had no idea was a thing until [just now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status)!)

*My first is the first of an outrageous utterance*

> An 'outrageous utterance' is HYPERBOLE. Take the 'first' part of this word to get **HYPER**.

*My second the second of appropriate circumstance*

> 'Appropriate circumstance' is CONTEXT. Take the 'second' (i.e. end) part of this word to get **TEXT**.

*My third's the essence of heat, why anything cools*

> This is **TRANSFER**, since things cool when heat is transferred to the environment or other objects.

*My last a procedure, all about the rules*

> This defines **PROTOCOL**. These four clues together give us *HYPERTEXT TRANSFER PROTOCOL*, which can be abbreviated to the four letters **HTTP**.

*Take the B's from my one*
*And the A's from my two*
*And with three's A & B's*
*My name I'll tell you*

> At this point I suspect the final number required is **418**. This can be created with the help of A1Z26. Since 'my one' (first letter) is H (8), take off two "B"s (i.e. 2s) and you have 8 - 2x2 = **4**. Since 'my two' (second letter) is T (20), take off two "A"s (i.e. 1s) and you have 20 - 2x1 = **18**. Combine the two to get 418.
>
>  *(OP points out that intended maths was simpler - taking "A's" to be the vowels AEIOU and "B's" to be the consonants (including Y), there are 4 consonants in clue 1 (**HYP**E**R**), 1 vowel in clue 2 (T**E**XT) and 8 letters in total in clue 3 (**TRANSFER**), enabling us to derive '418' that way...)*
>
>  The message produced in a web browser when error code HTTP 418 is generated is "The server refuses the attempt to brew coffee with a teapot."

This fits with the title, since:

> Both fire and water are involved in boiling tea in a pot, and when it is ready the teapot 'roars' (or whistles). This also tallies with the dislike of coffee in hint 1...
>
>  I would love to know how exactly you can generate this specific error message! If it's just a programmer's joke then it sounds like my cup of tea...!

Comment: Well done! For the number part though, I had something much simpler in mind. It is formed by counting the vowels (A's) and consonants (B's) from the first 3 words. All's well that ends well though :)

Comment: @greysaff Aha, I see - will edit that in too. Thanks :)

Comment: Wow. I would have NEVER gotten this. Great job, Stiv.